# Recycler view setLayoutManager on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my android app, I want to display data into `Recyclerview` layout. here I specified some code please refer it. because I don't know what is the reason behind it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here, I specify raw file of `RecyclerView`.

**raw.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtListTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HMS Scrap"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtListName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtListTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="HMS Scrap"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now, I post adapter file code

**adapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ListModal> listTitle;

    public ListAdapter(Context mContext, List<ListModal> listTitle) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.listTitle = listTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapter.ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.raw_list, parent, false);

        return new ListAdapter.ListViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.ListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListModal objListModal = listTitle.get(position);
        holder.txtListTitle.setText(objListModal.getList_name());
        holder.txtListTitle.setText(objListModal.getList_title());
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtListTitle, txtListName;
        CardView cvList;
        public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtListTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtListTitle);
            txtListName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtListName);
            cvList = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        }
    }
}
```

**Now Fragment.java**

```
RecyclerView rvDisplay;
private ListAdapter adapter;
private List<ListModal> lstmodal;

public CreateListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_list, container, false);

    rvDisplay = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvDisplay);

    lstmodal = new ArrayList<>();

    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvDisplay.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    makeJsonArrayRequest();
    return view;
}

private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {
    String cancel_req_tag = "list";

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_FOR_SELECT,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
             Log.d("OnResponse", response.toString());

             try {
                 // Parsing json array response
                 // loop through each json object
                 for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                     JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                     ListModal objListModal = new ListModal();
                     if (!jsonObject.isNull("list_name")) {
                         objListModal.list_name = jsonObject.getString("list_name"); //here we can fetch webservice field
                     }
                     if (!jsonObject.isNull("list_title")) {
                         objListModal.list_title = jsonObject.getString("list_title"); //here we can fetch webservice field
                     }

                     lstmodal.add(i, objListModal);
                 }

                 adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), lstmodal);
                 rvDisplay.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                 rvDisplay.setAdapter(adapter);

             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             VolleyLog.d("VolleyError", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });
}
```

Here I have tried this code I am getting this error please see work log

[image]

Comment: please refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ or this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

I think you have missed:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In your first block of code you say the layout file is named `fragment.xml` however in the Fragment code you call `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_list, ...)`

Make sure you inflate the same layout file as the fragment has.

Comment: yes i inflate the same layout file but I getting error in setLayoutManager @Mauin

Comment: try putting your code under onActivityCreated method

Answer (score 1):

Null object is usually caused when u use another layout instead of the one u are using. I had the same problem. Try inflating activity main instead of fragmentcreatelist...

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    rvDisplay = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvDisplay);

    lstmodal = new ArrayList<>();

    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvDisplay.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    makeJsonArrayRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the LinearLayoutManager by passing the context. Not the activity.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
```